# Combining column with list as data type

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe with column values such as below:

df:

[image]

I would like to combine all the values from column b into one list and remove duplicates.

Desired Output:

[Red, Blue, Green, Purple, Yellow]

So far I have tried using df['b].drop_duplicates().to_list() but am getting a list of lists as the output.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.explode()`:

```py
from ast import literal_eval
df["b"] = df["b"].apply(literal_eval)

print(df["b"].explode().drop_duplicates().to_list())
```

Prints:

```
['Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Yellow']
```

Comment: trying this and receiving the following output: ["['Red', 'Blue', 'Green']", "['Purple', 'Yellow']",    "['Red']"]. How to I combine them again?

Comment: @SaikrishnaSuresh Try to apply `literal_eval` (see my edit)